# Is "Windows Phone Silverlight 8" the same as "Windows Phone 8"?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an app that targets Windows Phone 8. Now I want to use [this compression library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.compression) which states:

> Supported Platforms:
>
> - .NET Framework 4.5
> - Windows 8
> - Windows Phone 8.1
> - **Windows Phone Silverlight 8**
> - Portable Class Libraries

Will my app still run on Windows Phone 8 devices? Is **Windows Phone Silverlight 8** the same as **Windows Phone 8**?

Comment: Im almost 100% sure its the same and this was just a verbose rebranding

Comment: If it helps I made a Windows Phone Silverlight 8 app recently and released it for WP8. Runs fine on that OS version <shameless plug>Chi-Town Food trucks</shameless plug>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is.

**Windows Phone Silverlight 8** is the name given to **Windows Phone 8** after the release of **Windows Phone 8.1**.

There is also **Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1** and **Windows Phone 8.1**. The difference between these two is that **Windows Phone 8.1** is compatible with **Windows Store Apps**, and **Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1** won't be compatible with that.

You can learn more about this here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn655121(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn655121%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)